# React native for scan mobile app

Tags: android, ios, react-native, barcode-scanner

I intent to develop a scan app using some native third-party library. Should I use Android SDK and Swift to develop it for each platform (Android and iOS) or use React Native and wrap these library together?

Comment: you can use this react native library https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera